# Introduction to Analysis: Actually Constant

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I more or less understand the concept of locally constant. If a function, $f(x)$, is locally constant then there is a sufficiently small neighborhood $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$ about $a$ such that $f(x)$ is constant.

However, what do they mean when they say Actually Constant?

Answer (score 2):

A little topology goes a long way here. The key to your underlying question is that real intervals are connected.

I leave proofs of the following as exercises for the reader. There are several paths you can take to get from Lemma 1 down to Theorem 5. Start with Corollary 2 or Corollary 3. If you took Corollary 2, prove Corollary 3 or Corollary 4. Note: it is probably easier to use Corollary 3 to get to Theorem 5 than Corollary 4.

Let $f\colon X\to Y$.

**Lemma 1:** $f$ is locally constant iff for each $p\in Y$, $f^{-1}\{p\}$ is open.

**Corollary 2:** $f$ is locally constant iff $f$ is continuous when $Y$ is given the discrete topology.

**Corollary 3:** $f$ is locally constant iff for each $S\subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}[S]$ is open.

**Corollary 4:** If $f$ is locally constant, then $f$ is continuous, regardless of the topology on $Y$.

**Theorem 5:** A locally constant function on a connected set is constant.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, if you look at the OP's comment on the other answer, you will understand.

Comment: Ah, I see. It would be good to add something leaving that clear. +1

Answer (score 1):

*Actually constant* means *constant over the whole domain*.

To find an example of a function (even a continuous one) that is locally constant but not actually constant, consider a non-connected domain such as $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ and consider the function $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$. Then $f$ is $0$ in $(0,1)$ and $2$ in $(2,3)$. It is not constant but it is locally constant.

Comment: Okay so if I was told to prove that a function that is locally constant on the domain [0,1) is actually constant on this interval, I just have to show it is constant throughout the domain.

Could I go about proving this by saying there is some supremum, 1, such that the function is constant on the interval [0,1)?

Comment: @Kevin_H, ask a separate question.