# Introduction to Analysis: Locally and Actually Constant

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-verification

I was given this problem for homework. I more a less understand it. I just need to somehow finalize my ideas. The problem reads:

> Prove that a function which is locally constant on $[0,1)$ is actually constant on $[0,1)$. Suggestions: one possibility would be to consider sup S, where S = {$a < 1$: $f(x)$ is constant on $[0,1)$}.

Idea here is that a function, $f(x)$ is locally constant if and only if for every $a$ $\in$ $A$, there exists a neighborhood, $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$, about $a$ such that f is constant on the neighborhood. When something is actually constant, it is constant all throughout the domain.

This is how I want to go about proving it.

Given S = {$a < 1$: $f(x)$ is constant on $[0,1)$}, let sup S = s such that s < 1. There $\exists \delta$ > $0$ such that $f(x)$ is constant on $(s-\delta, s+\delta)$. However, there $\exists$d $\in$ S such that $s - \delta < d \leq s$, so $f(x)$ is constant on $[0,d)$, therefore it has to be constant on $[0, s + \delta)$. However this is a contraction since s is the supremum on S. Thus sup S = 1 and f is actually constant on $[0,1)$.

This is how I want to go about and prove it however I feel like the proof is not strong enough. I still need to somehow prove it is actually constant throughout the domain, I just do not know how to approach it.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and thanks in advance for those who comment.

Comment: The problem with your proof is that $s$ will be $1$.

Comment: If you are familiar with connectedness, then my answer to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527945/introduction-to-analysis-actually-constant/527973#527973) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good. It can be simplified as follows:

Let $S=\{ x \in [0,1) : f(x)=f(0) \}$. Then $S$ is not empty because $0\in S$. Also, $S$ is bounded above (by say $1$). Hence $S$ has a sup, call it $s$. Since $1$ is an upper bound, we have $s\le 1$. If $s<1$, then there is a neighborhood of $s$ for which $f$ is locally constant. That same neighborhood contains an element $a$ of $S$. This implies that $s\in S$ because $f(s)=f(a)=f(0)$. But then we can extend $S$ to the right using that same neighborhood and $s$ is not the supremum of $S$. Therefore, $s=1$ and $f$ is constant.